# Try and catch block is not catching format exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to catch format exception but the program stops on try block and never reaches to catch block, what is the problem with the code
please help me?

```
private void txtBags_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (txtBags.Text != "" && PackingBox.Text != "") 
   {
      try 
      {
         txtQty.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(txtBags.Text)) * 
         (Convert.ToDecimal(PackingBox.Text)) / 100).ToString();
      } 
      catch (FormatException eX) 
      {
         MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
      }
   } 
   else 
   {
      txtQty.Text = "";
   }
}
```

I want to catch the exception and show the message to the user?
please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean it "stops on try block"?  When you step through in a debugger, what specifically happens?  What are the runtime values?  Is an exception thrown?  What are the details of that exception?

Comment: Your code does work. I am just wondering why you are not validating your input for being a decimal (`decimal.TryParse`) instead of catching exceptions.

Comment: "the program stops on try block" is the debugger putting you on Pause. Just hit [F5]

Comment: The code [catches the exception](https://rextester.com/QNCIN63215). I think Henk is right that it's just the debugger pausing to tell you there was an exception. Either way, `TryParse` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Why handle the exception at all? Why not just avoid it altogether by using [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)?:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpy(txtBags.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PackingBox.Text))
{
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtBags.Text, out var bags))
    {
        // handle parse failure
        return;
    }

    if (!Decimal.TryParse(PackingBox.Text, out var packingBox))
    {
        // handle parse failure
        return;
    }

    txtQty.Text = (bags * packingBox / 100).ToString();
}
```

If you're not building with Roslyn/are using an older version of C#, you might need to define the variable beforehand:

```
decimal bags;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtBags.Text, out bags))
```

And then the same with PackingBox, of course.

Comment: this code is not working it gives error of invalid arguments

Comment: thanks so much please tell me one more thing how can i handle parse failure @John

Comment: You could display a message, or indicator to the user.